# Does WatIn supports IE10 browser?

Tags: watin

We have test cases working for IE7,8 and 9 and need support for IE10.

Does WatIN supports it ?

Comment: I suspect it will run but there could well be a few differences in your test runs.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. The IE object of Watin is not support the IE 10. When you debug, you will found all the properties of IE object will casuse Exception

Comment: Thank you. With WatIN 2.1 we are able to make it.